# Unmerge spreadsheet cells and fill ex-merged empty cells with data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, merge

[breakApart()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#breakapart) works fine, but I'd like to fill the empty cells with merged cell's data.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var sheetRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()); 
sheetRange.breakApart();
```

I got the value I need, but how can I get the cells to fill?

```
var value = (cell.isPartOfMerge() ? cell.getMergedRanges()[0].getCell(1,1) : cell).getValue();
```

Comment: Do you think it might be possible using formulas?

Comment: @KrzysztofDołęgowski I don't think so - formulas are not suitable for cell merging, afaik. Play a bit with google app - it's free, pretty easy to use, and has a huge potential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have the value, You can  `setValue()`  the desired value over the entire range and all the range will be filled with the same value.

```js
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const sheetRange = sheet.getDataRange(); 
sheetRange
  .getMergedRanges()
  .forEach(range => range.setValue(range.breakApart().getValue()));
```

`getValue()` already returns only the  value in the top left cell. So the above chaining works.

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko To brag, I made it easy :)