# Google Sheets unmerge and populate (both down and right)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to unmerge and populate the original value to unmerged cells for differents sets of data.

There are columns that includes merged cells in different rows.

```
function myFunction() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var sheetRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns());
 var mergedRanges = sheetRange.getMergedRanges();
 sheetRange.breakApart(); 
}
```

This code works fine to unmerge. Still, I need to populate new empty cells created after unmerge.

Comment: Kindly clarify what you want to achieve. Either attach the screenshots of the sheet with sample data to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using the answer to this question:
[Unmerge spreadsheet cells and fill ex-merged empty cells with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64395621/unmerge-spreadsheet-cells-and-fill-ex-merged-empty-cells-with-data)

```
function myFunction() {
  // It doesn't work instantaneously. I would take ~20 seconds depending on the size of your data.
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  // Get First three columns (you can change this part to adapt)
  var sheetRangeCol = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), 3);
  
  // Get 2 raws starting with 4th (you can change this part to adapt)
  var sheetRangeRow = sheet.getRange(4, 1, 2, sheet.getMaxColumns());


  sheetRangeCol
  .getMergedRanges()
  .forEach(range => range.setValue(range.breakApart().getValue()));
  
  sheetRangeRow
  .getMergedRanges()
  .forEach(range => range.setValue(range.breakApart().getValue()));
}
```

It both breaks merged cells in the range that you provide and then populates the original valute to newly created cells.