# How can I make an array of ranges properly merge in Google Sheets with GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a cross-spreadsheet importing tool which transfers (or at least pretends to) both data and format from one spreadsheet to another. So far, the thing that has not been working as (I think) it should, is cell merging.

Currently, I am trying to get all merged cells from the source range with `.getMergedRanges()`, which gives me a 57-element-long array of ranges, which I then loop with `.getRange(array[index]).merge()`, but when looping it seems to not be able to merge all the ranges properly despite the program actually running through all indexes.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
function uploadPlan(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  //var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var uploadSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Course Plan');
  var sheetIndex = uploadSheet.getIndex()-1;
  var repoID = ss.getRangeByName('planRepoID').getValue().toString();
  var planRepo = SpreadsheetApp.openById(repoID);
  var uploadStandard = ss.getRangeByName('planUploadStandard').getValue().toString();
  var uploadRange = ss.getRangeByName('planUploadRange');
  var planID = ss.getRangeByName('planIdentifier').getValue();
  planID = planID.split(" ").join("_");
  var downloadRange = planRepo.getRangeByName(planID);

  switch(uploadStandard){

    case 'BAEFCO Standard':

      uploadRange = s.getRange(uploadRange.getRow(), uploadRange.getColumn(), downloadRange.getNumRows(), downloadRange.getNumColumns());
      uploadRange = sh[sheetIndex].getRange(uploadRange.getA1Notation());

      var mergedRanges = downloadRange.getMergedRanges();

      for(var i=0; i<mergedRanges.length; i++){

        sh[sheetIndex].getRange(mergedRanges[i].getA1Notation()).merge();
        console.log(mergedRanges[i].getA1Notation());
      }

      uploadRange.setBackgrounds(downloadRange.getBackgrounds());

      break;

    default: 

      //ui.alert("Please select a supported Import Standard.");
    
  }

}
```

I expect it to merge all cells properly, but it goes through some and then stops working.

[Screenshot example of what happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSmv8.png)

I have also tried adding pauses and segmenting the merging in parts, thinking it could help, but alas it made no difference.

Any help, or alternative way to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated; please excuse my inexperienced coding.

Comment: I would avoid the use of merge cells.  They are a PITA and the only data you get from them is their upper left corner the rest is blank

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unmerge spreadsheet cells and fill ex-merged empty cells with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64395621/unmerge-spreadsheet-cells-and-fill-ex-merged-empty-cells-with-data)

Comment: @Cooper, I would love to, but the aesthetics here are what's important unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do in cases like this where format and merged cells are involved is to create a provisional copy of the entire tab that contains the range in particular into the destination spreadsheet. Then with the option "copyTo" I can copy the range with all its characteristics, and then delete that backup sheet.
I oversimplified your code because I didn't have all your named ranges to test but I'm sure you'll be able to easily copy the needed lines. Just a very dummy example of something copied with this option, with colours, alignations, merged cells, etc.:
[image]

Here's the code:

```
function uploadplan(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();   
  var planRepo = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Tz5_xPoKAdPBOVGvNByFar7PGmdxOHeyzA2WIZhs1LE")
  var downloadRange = planRepo.getRangeByName("downloadrange");
 //these first lines you should better use the definitions in your own function. What's important is next:

  var backup = s.copyTo(planRepo).setName("Backup") //Is 's' the the sheet where you have the named range?, if not please change it

  var uploadRange = planRepo.getRangeByName("Backup!uploadrange"); //It's important the change of names of the previous step, because that's what will allow you to access the named range. If 'Backup' isn't possible because you're using the name for another sheet, change Backup in this line and the previous one with another temporary value


  uploadRange.copyTo(downloadRange) // This copies everything, included formulas
  uploadRange.copyTo(downloadRange,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false) //If you want you can use this last line if you want to set only values after having copied the formats and merged cells in the previous step
  
  planRepo.deleteSheet(backup) // and you delete that backup sheet
```

}

Comment: I see what you're doing here, and seems like a sensible solution! I wanted to avoid things like these but now that I see it in code it doesn't seem too bad of an option. Thank you very much!